# How do I create an If-Then-Else in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some negative values coming back from a query. I would like them to just be zero.
How do I write a condition in my sql query that returns zero if the value is below a certain value.

sol:

```
CASE WHEN  CONVERT(float,dt.FQI53X02_101)  <  1.3  THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(float,dt.FQI53X02_101) END AS  FQI53X02_101
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont use If-Then-Else in the actual query (you can use them but thats something else)...

What you use is a Case statement... Try this

```
Select
    Case When [Value] < 0 Then 0 Else [Value] End
From 
    Example
```

Comment: my variation of your sugestion is: "select  dt.* , Case  FQI53X02_101 When < 1.3 Then 0 Else  FQI53X02_101 End  as hhh 
from" I get an error back on the less-than operator...not suer why

Comment: Okay I got it "CASE WHEN  CONVERT(float,dt.FQI53X02_101)  <  1.3  THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(float,dt.FQI53X02_101) END AS  FQI53X02_101"

Answer (score 5):

If you want it as part of your query, wrap the return inside a CASE statement.  Example from MSDN is below

```
SELECT     'Price Category' = 

        CASE 

            WHEN price IS NULL THEN 'Not yet priced'

            WHEN price < 10 THEN 'Very Reasonable Title'

            WHEN price >= 10 and price < 20 THEN 'Coffee Table Title'

            ELSE 'Expensive book!'

        END,

    CAST(title AS varchar(20)) AS 'Shortened Title'

FROM titles

ORDER BY price
```

Answer (score 2):

```
( ABS(Value) + Value ) / 2
```

edit - this doesn't work now the question has changed

Comment: Nice one. +1 (rubbish to get 15 chars)